# Checkboxes with multiple values not submitting

Tags: php

I am having some issues with submitting checkbox values that are dynamically craeted with PHP.

Data is outputted inside a table. Each row displays a users information. Below is an example of one of those rows.

```
        <tr id="linguist7">
            <td valign="middle">
                <div class="checkbox check-default">
                    <input id="checkbox7" name="linguistCheckbox[]" type=
                    "checkbox" value="fsh5ge4egrsgs/*/German/*/Italian">
                </div>
            </td>

            <td valign="middle"><a href=
            "javascript:void();"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Joe
            Bloggs&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

            <td valign="middle"><span class="muted">German into
            Italian</span></td>

            <td><span class="muted">EUR 50</span></td>

            <td valign="middle">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class=
                    "progress-bar progress-bar-success animate-progress-bar"
                    data-percentage="90%" style="width:90%;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Once the form is submitted I am displaying the checkbox values using var_dump (This is just for testing purposes).

```
$selectedLinguists = $_POST['linguistCheckbox'];
var_dump($selectedLinguists);
```

Var_Dump is just displaying "NULL". So it appears the checkboxes are not being submitted.

So far, my only guess is that it's to do with the formatting of my table but I'm really not sure.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have added another checkbox that is displayed outside the table and it submits fine. Is this an issues with the checkboxes being inside a table?

EDIT2: Link to form: http://jsfiddle.net/4dxv6/

Comment: where are your form tags?

Comment: Is it inside the form? And how is it submitted

Comment: try var_dump($_REQUEST) to see what's submitted by your form at all.

Comment: @RoyalBg It's submitted using POST. All the other data inside the same form submits perfectly.

Comment: I don't see in inside a form?

Comment: @RoyalBg "Below is an example of one of those rows." - I have not included the entire file as it's too big. I have included only a sample of one of the outputted rows. They are all the same.

Comment: It works when I run it. (Guessing what you surround the above snippet with) Can you add all your code? Or just the form part to get a working example

Comment: If I don't check any of the checkboxes I also get NULL

Comment: @smerlung Yes, but when I check the checkboxes I get NULL. It makes sense that you get NULL when you don't check any boxes as the array data is empty. Link is here - http://jsfiddle.net/4dxv6/

Comment: If I run the code in your link, it works. The only thing I change is the action="Submit Script" which I remove.

Comment: have you tried
<pre><?php print_r($_POST);?></pre> ?

Answer (score 0):

If wrap your code in the following way then it works.

```
<?php
$linguistCheckbox = $_POST['linguistCheckbox'];
var_dump($linguistCheckbox);
?>

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr id="linguist7">
            <td valign="middle">
                <div class="checkbox check-default">
                    <input id="checkbox7" name="linguistCheckbox[]" type=
                    "checkbox" value="fsh5ge4egrsgs/*/German/*/Italian">
                </div>
            </td>

            <td valign="middle"><a href=
            "javascript:void();"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Joe
            Bloggs&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

            <td valign="middle"><span class="muted">German into
            Italian</span></td>

            <td><span class="muted">EUR 50</span></td>

            <td valign="middle">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class=
                    "progress-bar progress-bar-success animate-progress-bar"
                    data-percentage="90%" style="width:90%;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```